# How to create sql db2 data table using python?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, db2

I would like to run an sql db2 query on python that will create a data table in a public schema but I'm stuck because of this error

> ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.

Below is the Python code I'm using, I have deleted the private information.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

#connection string
user = "xxx"
pwd = "xxx"
host = "xxx"
port = "xxx"
db = "xxx"
conn_strng = "redshift+psycopg2://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s" %(user,pwd,host,port,db)

#establish connection
engine = create_engine(conn_strng)

with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():
    pd.read_sql("""
            drop table if exists public.fc_SER_ACC_By_DLCX_Date;
                create table public.fc_SER_ACC_By_DLCX_Date as 
                SELECT DLCX_Date, tool_id as DLCX_Tool,Model, avg(SQZSER) as SQZSER_Mean, avg(SQZSER_BASE) as SQZSER_BASE_Mean, 
                avg(PRED_ACC_SMR) as PRED_ACC_SMR_Mean, avg(PRED_ACC_CMR) as PRED_ACC_CMR_Mean, count(slider_id) as Tested_Sliders
                FROM (SELECT DISTINCT a.slider_id, LEFT(a.product_id,2) as Model, 
                a.xti_wrn1_p23 AS SQZSER,a.SER0 AS SQZSER_BASE, a.FOM2 AS PRED_ACC_SMR, a.FOM1 AS PRED_ACC_CMR,
                TRUNC(c.transaction_date_time) as DLCX_Date, c.tool_id
                FROM ah.param_jade_wide a
                LEFT JOIN ah.param_lap_summary b ON (a.wafer_id, a.row_number) = (b.wafer_id, b.row_number)
                LEFT JOIN ah.his_job c ON c.job_number = b.job_number
                WHERE c.transaction_date_time > '2020-03-01'
                AND LEFT(a.product_id,2) IN ('C3')
                AND b.source_system_code IN ('MFG2.SLDR.LAPRUN')
                AND a.xti_wrn1_p23 between -10 and 0
                AND a.SER0 between -10 and 0
                AND c.operation_id IN ('510150')
                AND a.retest_number = 0
                AND a.class_description IN ('PROD')
                AND NOT c.tool_id = 0 AND NOT c.tool_id in (''))
                group by DLCX_Date, DLCX_Tool, Model

                Union

                SELECT DLCX_Date, tool_id as DLCX_Tool,Model, avg(SQZSER) as SQZSER_Mean, avg(SQZSER_BASE) as SQZSER_BASE_Mean, 
                avg(PRED_ACC_SMR) as PRED_ACC_SMR_Mean,'0'PRED_ACC_CMR_Mean, count(slider_id) as Tested_Sliders
                FROM (SELECT DISTINCT a.slider_id, LEFT(a.product_id,2) as Model, 
                a.XTI_WRN1_P19 AS SQZSER,a.XTI_WRN1_P18 AS SQZSER_BASE, a.XTI_RSVD0 AS PRED_ACC_SMR, 
                TRUNC(c.transaction_date_time) as DLCX_Date, c.tool_id
                FROM ah.param_jade_wide a
                LEFT JOIN ah.param_lap_summary b ON (a.wafer_id, a.row_number) = (b.wafer_id, b.row_number)
                LEFT JOIN ah.his_job c ON c.job_number = b.job_number
                WHERE c.transaction_date_time > '2020-03-01'
                AND LEFT(a.product_id,2) IN ('L2','L3')
                AND b.source_system_code IN ('MFG2.SLDR.LAPRUN')
                AND c.operation_id IN ('510150')
                AND a.XTI_WRN1_P19 between -10 and 0
                AND a.XTI_WRN1_P18 between -10 and 0
                AND a.retest_number = 0
                AND a.class_description IN ('PROD')
                AND NOT c.tool_id = 0 AND NOT c.tool_id in (''))
                group by DLCX_Date, DLCX_Tool, Model
                order by DLCX_Date;
                commit;""", conn)
conn.close()
engine.dispose()

print("Table has been updated!")
```

Please help in fixing my code and thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are using Pandas to run action queries? Do you want to import the created table into a data frame?

Comment: got your point. I thought I need pandas function to read my sql script. So how can I run my query? please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error indicates Pandas `read_sql` cannot import data into a data frame since you only have DDL actions: `DROP TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE` and nothing that return rows like `SELECT`.

If not using Pandas for data analytics, simply run your queries with SQL Alchemy [transactions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#using-transactions). And no need to `close` using context manager like `with`:

```
with engine.connect() as conn:
   with conn.begin()
      conn.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.fc_SER_ACC_By_DLCX_Date;""")
      conn.execute("""CREATE TABLE public.fc_SER_ACC_By_DLCX_Date AS
                      ...
                   """)
```

Or combined:

```
with engine.begin() as conn:
   conn.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.fc_SER_ACC_By_DLCX_Date;""")
   conn.execute("""CREATE TABLE public.fc_SER_ACC_By_DLCX_Date AS
                   ...
                """)
```

And if you really do need a data frame, use `engine` object in [`read_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) after transactions:

```
df = pd.read_sql("""SELECT * FROM public.fc_SER_ACC_By_DLCX_Date;""", engine)
```